# Usar <Link> dentro de un objeto

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Pregunta de novato que he buscado pero sin éxito ¿como puedo agregar un `<Link>` dentro de un valor de un objeto? También podría extender la pregunta si dentro de ese objeto tengo muchos tags HTML, que parcialmente lo pude resolver usando `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` pero no funciona con . El código es el siguiente:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
    
const features = [
  {
    name: 'Fecha',
    description: `Domingo 19 de Noviembre 2022. ${<Link href="#">Ingresa aquí</Link>}`,
  },
  {
    name: 'Hora',
    description: `${<Link href="#">Another link</Link>}`,
  }
];

export default function Example() {
  return (
    {features.map((feature) => (
      <div key={feature.name}>
        <div>{feature.name}</div>
        <p>{feature.description}</p>
      </div>
    ))}
)}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es agregar un componente react dentro de un objeto Javascript?

Comment: Si, perdón que no especifique. Estoy usando Nextjs. El objeto viene del API y en algunos valores tienen links, algo así como el contenido de un blog.

Comment: Esto responde tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073258/react-storing-components-in-an-object

Comment: No sabría responderle si la sugerencia que usted me ha pasado se puede aplicar con el ejemplo que introduje en este posteo.

Comment: Podrías hacer la prueba entonces?